# How to create a HTML form from a Json

Tags: html, json, activiti

I'm using Activiti and I have a form like this:

[image]

When I use Rest API, that form will be returned with Json like this:

```
{
    "formKey": null,
    "deploymentId": "21151",
    "processDefinitionId": null,
    "processDefinitionUrl": null,
    "taskId": "21159",
    "taskUrl": "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks/21159",
    "formProperties": [
        {
            "id": "firstName",
            "name": "First Name",
            "type": "string",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": true,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "lastName",
            "name": "Last Name",
            "type": "string",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "phoneNumber",
            "name": "Phone Number",
            "type": "string",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "dateTime",
            "name": "Date Time",
            "type": "date",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": "dd/MM/yyyy",
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "city",
            "name": "City",
            "type": "enum",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "name": "TPHCM"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "HN"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert this Json into a Html Form with that inputs in Json result. I search many post about using library but I can't make my Json result like that library required. So any way to do this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Parse the json, iterate over it's formProperties array, create an input for each prop, append to form.

Comment: Yes, that's basically how you do it ^^ Please create a [mcve] showing us what you tried

Comment: Please be aware that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Questions along the lines of  : "These are my requirements, please give me a solution" are not well received. What specifically are you having trouble with? Extracting info from JSON? Creating and inserting DOM elements? etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    **Store your json response in a variable.eg:var json;**
As the json is getting from a Rest API,it can be stored in a variable.So that we can use that to proceed the form creation.We can iterate the formProperties to create the form inputs.
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>


    <script>
    var formData = json.formProperties;
    var inputs = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
        if(formData[i].id == 'city'){
        inputs += '<label>'+formData[i].id+'</label></br><select><option>'+formData[i].enumValues[0].name+'</option><option>'+formData[i].enumValues[1].name+'</option> </select>'+'</br></br>';
        }else if(formData[i].id == 'dateTime'){
        inputs += '<label>'+formData[i].id+'</label></br><input type="date"/>'+'</br></br>';
        }else{
       inputs += '<label>'+formData[i].id+'</label></br><input  type="text" value="" id="' + formData[i].id + '">'+'</br></br>';
       }
     }
     document.getElementById('form').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', inputs);
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: As the json is getting from a Rest API,it can be stored in a variable.So that we can use that to proceed the form creation.We can iterate the formProperties to create the form inputs.

Answer (score 1):

First a comment, you really should be showing in your question what you have tried so far and elaborate on what specifically you are having trouble with.

This technique uses DOM objects to create the form. It uses a document fragment to limit the number of actual updates to the DOM. Hopefully the comments in the code are self explanatory.

```js
//Just for demo purposes - this would be your API Call
var data = getData();

//Get the bit we need
var formData = data.formProperties;

//Call our function to carete the form
createForm(formData);

//The magic
function createForm(data){
  //Create a fragment so we aren't constantly updating the DOM
  var container = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  data.forEach(function(formProp){
  //Create a row div with a class
  var rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
  rowDiv.classList.add("rowDiv");
  
  //Create a label
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.setAttribute("for", formProp.id);
  label.innerHTML = formProp.name;
  
  //Create a form element
  var formElement = document.createElement(formProp.type == "enum" ? "select" : "input");
  //Set it's properties
  formElement.id = formProp.id;
  formElement.name = formProp.id;
  formElement.required = formProp.required;
  formElement.readOnly = !formProp.writable;
  
  
  //Do some stuff if the form element is required
  if(formProp.required){
    rowDiv.classList.add("required");    
  }
  
  //Do stuf for not select 
  if(formProp.type != "enum"){
    formElement.value = formProp.value;
    
    if(formProp.type == "date") {
      formElement.type = "date";
    }
    //Add any other types here
    else {
      //falback to text
      formElement.type = "text";
    }
  }
  //Add the enum values
  else {
    formProp.enumValues.forEach(function(formEnum){
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = formEnum.id;
      opt.text = formEnum.name;   
      opt.selected = formEnum.id == formProp.value;
      formElement.appendChild(opt);
    });    
  }
  
  //Add label and element to div
  rowDiv.append(label);
  rowDiv.append(formElement);  
  
  //Apend div to fragment
  container.appendChild(rowDiv);
  });
  //Add fragment to form
  document.getElementById("mainForm").appendChild(container);
}



function getData(){
var data = {
    "formKey": null,
    "deploymentId": "21151",
    "processDefinitionId": null,
    "processDefinitionUrl": null,
    "taskId": "21159",
    "taskUrl": "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks/21159",
    "formProperties": [
        {
            "id": "firstName",
            "name": "First Name",
            "type": "string",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": true,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "lastName",
            "name": "Last Name",
            "type": "string",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "phoneNumber",
            "name": "Phone Number",
            "type": "string",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "dateTime",
            "name": "Date Time",
            "type": "date",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": "dd/MM/yyyy",
            "enumValues": []
        },
        {
            "id": "city",
            "name": "City",
            "type": "enum",
            "value": null,
            "readable": true,
            "writable": true,
            "required": false,
            "datePattern": null,
            "enumValues": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "name": "TPHCM"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "HN"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
return data;
};
```

```css
/*Add some styling for required*/
.required::after {
  content: " *";
  color:#F00;
}

.rowDiv {
  padding:2px;
}

.rowDiv label {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <fieldset id="mainForm">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="buttons">
  <input type="submit" value="Complete Task">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset From">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```